# Troubleshooting `$ wget -A.pdf -r site.com`

Tags: wget

I am trying to get homework papers with the command but for some reason, it does not return them. Any idea why?

```
$ wget -A.pdf -r -nd https://noppa.aalto.fi/noppa/kurssi/mat-2.3152/viikkoharjoitukset/
```

My goal is to download all homework and then merge them with `pdftk` and then search over them with some program -- but I cannot proceed (without again going to Firefox DownloadThemAll -plugin) until I get this working. Ideas why not working? Have sysadmins set up some bans for wgets or why does it fail?

I get only this robots.txt -file:

```
$ cat robots.txt 
User-agent: *
Disallow: /

User-agent: Googlebot
Allow: /
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
```

Comment: So what does happen when you type this command?

Comment: ..it downloads only the robots.txt -file but no pdf altough I can see my course homeworks on the site.

Comment: ...this is no fake site, official site by Aalto Uni (more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aalto_University) about it). I have tried this elsewhere time-to-time and worked so are there some special restrictions or why wget does not work? Because of https?

Comment: Does regular download via a web browser work?

Comment: @FaheemMitha: ofc -- used DownloadThemAll -addon in Firefox, now just wanted to use wget to replace it. Rush discovered the problem, an issue with robots.txt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is in `robots.txt`. Wget looks on it and sees

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

You can use tell wget to ignore the `robots.txt` file:

```
wget -A.pdf -r -nd -e robots=off  https://noppa.aalto.fi/noppa/kurssi/mat-2.3152/viikkoharjoitukset/
```

And it will work.

Comment: Yes this must be right `"$wget -d -nd -r -A.pdf SITE 2&>debug"`, verified by debug msgs: `"Not following https://noppa.aalto.fi/noppa/kurssi/mat-2.3152/viikkoharjoitukset/laskari_1_s.1-8__ei_kotihtavaa.pdf because robots.txt forbids it.
Decided NOT to load it."` -- why have they this kind of stupid restrictions, no search engine can search them?!

Comment: I think it's a kind of protection from site copying. As you can see, google is allowed, so it is protection only from grabbers.

Comment: what is `site grabbing`? I know that sysadmins have banned services that provided better service than the official service (...well it is a bit...) and it is currently much harder to find anything because search engines do not index things. I can see only reason for the paranoia to hide information, I have only suspects... but thank you, got it worknig --back to studying. Some people still think we have no internet, kosh.

Comment: I meant site copying. May be it is only my country local slang. (: